# Using appendTo() on the parent `ul` of $this (current) element

Tags: jquery, syntax

I'm having difficulty with some syntax.

**JS**

```
function sortAlpha(a,b){
       return a.innerHTML > b.innerHTML ? 1 : -1;
};

$('.brick ul li').each(function() {
       $(this).sort(sortAlpha).appendTo('ul');
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="studio" class="brick">
<div class="listlist">
<h3 class="title">Studio</h3>
<ul class="list">
    <li class="odd">
        <a href="#">
            <span class="title">Apple</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="even">
    <span class="title"><a href="#">Cat</span>
            </a>
    </li>
    <li class="odd">
        <span class="title">
                        <a href="#">Bar</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

I would like to append `$this` `li` to it's own parent `ul` not all the lists

Edit: Just to make sure I'm selecting the correct li and parent. Thanks

Comment: Can't you just do this:  $(this).sort(sortAlpha).appendTo('.brick ul'); ?

Comment: I have more than 1 `.brick` lists. It will sort the first list then append the result to all of the `.brick` lists.

Comment: Can you post your markup and show what the end-result should be?

Comment: $(this).closest(".brick").append($(this).sort(sortAlpha)); How about that?

Comment: What is sort(), that is not standard core jQuery.

Comment: Plus you are not removing the original items, you are appending to it again so the list will grow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have inaccurate `html`, not properly nested, anyways, you may try this, I've answered assuming that the first `li` have the right nesting, as given below

```
<li class="odd">
    <a href="#">
        <span class="title">Apple</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

[**Working Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/CCZcN/10/).

```
// Sorter
function sorter(){
    var arr=[], len=$('.brick').find('ul.list li').length;    
    $('.brick ul.list li').each(function(i) {
        var el=$(this).find('a span').text();
        arr.push(el);
        if(i==(len-1))
        {
            arr=sortAlpha(arr);
            var ul=$(this).closest('ul.list').empty();
            $.each(arr, function(k, v){
                var cls=(k%2) ? 'even':'odd',
                li=$('<li/>', {'class':cls}),
                a=$('<a/>',{'href':'#'}).append($('<span/>', {'class':'title'}).text(v));
                ul.append(li.append(a));
            });
        }
    });    
}

//Sort helper
function sortAlpha(list){
    var result = [], map = [];
    for (var i=0, length = list.length; i < length; i++) {
        map.push({ index: i, value: list[i].toLowerCase() });
    }
    map.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.value > b.value ? 1 : -1;
    });
    for (var i=0, length = map.length; i < length; i++) {
        result.push(list[map[i].index]);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `closest()` method to traverse the DOM and find the `UL` that is the parent -

```
$(this).sort(sortAlpha).appendTo($(this).closest('ul'));
```

http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Answer (score 0):

If you are unsure of the parent element, then use this

```
$(this).sort(sortAlpha).appendTo($(this).parent("ul"));
```

If you are still not sure that parent is going to right above the DOM Tree then use `.closest()`

```
$(this).sort(sortAlpha).appendTo($(this).closest("ul"));
```

But, performance will better if you uniquely identify the `ul` with an `id` like

```
<ul id="meParent">
   ...
</ul>
```

Then

```
$(this).sort(sortAlpha).appendTo("#meParent");
```